# Appending lines to a file, then reading them

Tags: python

I want to append or write multiple lines to a file. I believe the following code appends one line:

```
with open(file_path,'a') as file:
    file.write('1')
```

My first question is that if I do this:

```
with open(file_path,'a') as file:
    file.write('1')
    file.write('2')
    file.write('3')
```

Will it create a file with the following content?

```
1
2
3
```

Second question—if I later do:

```
with open(file_path,'r') as file:
    first = file.read()
    second = file.read()
    third = file.read()
```

Will that read the content to the variables so that `first` will be `1`, `second` will be `2` etc? If not, how do I do it?

Comment: Question 1, question 2... is this a homework question?

Comment: @BobDylan irrelevant -- it's clearly asked and easy to understand.

Comment: It doesn't seem clear to me what the OP is trying to do at all. Append multiple lines from *what*? A list containing data, or does the OP need to loop through a range of numbers (`range`)? Is the OP trying to write multiple lines to a file or read individual lines from a file? The title of the question is about *appending* multiple lines to a file, not reading from the file

Comment: So is the question about reading individual values from a file, or about appending multiple lines to a file? It isn't clear at all and all questions seem to assume the former despite the question title.

Comment: Hi Bob, it's about both

Comment: @MichaelLaszlo with respect: the only people who have edited the content of his post are you and I. The question hasn't been changed "substantially," or even "at all."

Comment: @AdamSmith Hmm. You're right. I must have misread the question the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1: No.

`file.write` simple writes whatever you pass to it to the position of the pointer in the file. `file.write("Hello "); file.write("World!")` will produce a file with contents `"Hello World!"`

You can write a whole line either by appending a newline character (`"\n"`) to each string to be written, or by using the `print` function's `file` keyword argument (which I find to be a bit cleaner)

```
with open(file_path, 'a') as f:
    print('1', file=f)
    print('2', file=f)
    print('3', file=f)
```

*N.B. `print` to file doesn't always add a newline, but `print` itself does by default!* `print('1', file=f, end='')` is identical to `f.write('1')`

#### Question 2: No.

`file.read()` reads the whole file, not one line at a time. In this case you'll get

```
first == "1\n2\n3"
second == ""
third == ""
```

This is because after the first call to `file.read()`, the pointer is set to the end of the file. Subsequent calls try to read from the pointer to the end of the file. Since they're in the same spot, you get an empty string. A better way to do this would be:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:  # `file` is a bad variable name since it shadows the class
    lines = f.readlines()
    first = lines[0]
    second = lines[1]
    third = lines[2]
```

Or:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    first, second, third = f.readlines()  # fails if there aren't exactly 3 lines
```

Comment: Note that his write example doesn't actually add newlines, so the content of his file won't be `"1\n2\n3"`, it'll just be `123` and this answer won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is no. You're writing individual characters. You would have to read them  out individually.

Also, note that `file.read()` returns the full contents of the file.

If you wrote individual characters and you want to read individual characters, process the result of `file.read()` as a string.

```
text = open(file_path).read()
first = text[0]
second = text[1]
third = text[2]
```

As for the second question, you should write newline characters, `'\n'`, to terminate each line that you write to the file.

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as out_file:
  out_file.write('1\n')
  out_file.write('2\n')
  out_file.write('3\n')
```

To read the lines, you can use `file.readlines()`.

```
lines = open(file_path).readlines()
first = lines[0]   # -> '1\n'
second = lines[1]  # -> '2\n'
third = lines[2]   # -> '3\n'
```

If you want to get rid of the newline character at the end of each line, use `strip()`, which discards all whitespace before and after a string. For example:

```
first = lines[0].strip()   # -> '1'
```

Better yet, you can use `map` to apply `strip()` to every line.

```
lines = list(map(str.strip, open(file_path).readlines()))
first = lines[0]   # -> '1'
second = lines[1]  # -> '2'
third = lines[2]   # -> '3'
```

Comment: You don't need a `lambda` for your `map`, just apply `str.strip`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `str.strip`. Fixed.

Comment: Sure! It's the unbound method form of `"some string here".strip`. The unbound method accepts an argument while the bound method acts on `self`.

Answer (score 0):

**Writing multiple lines to a file**

This will depend on how the data is stored. For writing individual values, your current example is:

```
with open(file_path,'a') as file:
    file.write('1')
    file.write('2')
    file.write('3')
```

The file will contain the following:

```
123
```

It will also contain whatever contents it had previously since it was opened to append. To write newlines, you must explicitly add these or use `writelines()`, which expects an iterable.

Also, I don't recommend using `file` as an object name since it is a keyword, so I will use `f` from here on out.

For instance, here is an example where you have a list of values that you write using `write()` and explicit newline characters:

```
my_values = ['1', '2', '3']

with open(file_path,'a') as f:
    for value in my_values:
        f.write(value + '\n')
```

But a better way would be to use `writelines()`. To add newlines, you could join them with a list comprehension:

```
my_values = ['1', '2', '3']

with open(file_path,'a') as f:
    f.writelines([value + '\n' for value in my_values])
```

If you are looking for printing a range of numbers, you could use a for loop with `range` (or `xrange` if using Python 2.x and printing a lot of numbers).

**Reading individual lines from a file**

To read individual lines from a file, you can also use a for loop:

```
my_list = []

with open(file_path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_list.append(line.strip())  # strip out newline characters
```

This way you can iterate through the lines of the file returned with a for loop (or just process them as you read them, particularly if it's a large file).

Comment: Probably easier to explain `"\n".join(my_values)` than it is to try and cram "Hey, here's list comprehensions" into an answer about basic file I/O

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah but `writelines()` expects a list and the user clearly wants newlines. I probably should just remove it but meh, when I initially wrote this nobody's answer addressed the OP's question about writing multiple lines but the OP gives no indication of *how* the data is stored